# creating objects for 1:n relation with prisma

Tags: typescript, orm, prisma

I have two models, Fish and BoardFish
with a 1:1 relation - BoardFish is a type of Fish
I created some seed Fish with named types.

how can I do this in Prisma? I think i have the schema setup, but inserting data isn't really documented apart from fancy/nested types.

schema:

```
model Fish {
    name      String      @id
    boardFish BoardFish[]
}

model BoardFish {
    id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
    name     String
    fishType Fish   @relation(fields: [name], references: [name])
}
```

try to create:

```
        let fishes = []
        for (let c = 0; c < fishCount; c++) {
            const fishType = await prisma.fish.findFirst({ where: { name: 'salmon' } })
            const fishData = {
                fishType: fishType!.name,
                // name: 'salmon',
                px: 0,
                py: 0,
            }
            const fish = await prisma.boardFish.create({ data: fishData })
            fishes.push(fish)
        }
```

but I'm unable to do the insertion:

```
→ 35 const fish = await prisma.boardFish.create({
       data: {
         fishType: 'salmon',
                   ~~~~~~~~
         px: 3,
         py: 5
       }
     })

Argument fishType: Got invalid value 'salmon' on prisma.createOneBoardFish. Provided String, expected FishCreateNestedOneWithoutBoardFishInput:
type FishCreateNestedOneWithoutBoardFishInput {
  create?: FishCreateWithoutBoardFishInput | FishUncheckedCreateWithoutBoardFishInput
  connectOrCreate?: FishCreateOrConnectWithoutBoardFishInput
  connect?: FishWhereUniqueInput
}
```

The types involved are pretty hard to follow, Prisma seems to really take the cake for most "magic" with thousands of lines of auto generated code, which I've been digging through without much luck.

Comment: two things; first: if you want 1:1 relationships, edit your prisma schema to remove the square braces on `boardFish BoardFish[]`, second: to create a related record use prisma's [connect](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#connect) api. It looks like you are just doing it with a string `'salmon'`

Comment: yep thanks, i missed docs on `connect` but makes sense!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have 1:1 relations, I think the schema needs to look more like this:

```
model Fish {
    name      String      @id
    boardFish BoardFish? // removed autogenerated `[]` and made optional
}

model BoardFish {
    id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
    name     String
    fishType Fish   @relation(fields: [name], references: [name])
}
```

When creating a related record, use prisma's [connect](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#connect) api

```js
const fish = await prisma.boardFish.create({
  data: {
    fishType: {
      connect: { name: 'salmon' }, // or `connectOrCreate` if it doesn't exist
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: hey this worked thanks! I missed the `connect` docs